# Does pyCharm automaticall add before git commit?

Tags: git, pycharm, addition, commit

I know that we should first do `git add` before we do `git commit`.

However, when using the PyCharm GUI it becomes unclear if adding the files is necessary or not before commiting. That is because PyCharm seems to implicitly add the files when one presses the PyCharm *Commit* button. I am saying that because I see in the PyCharm console these messages after I have pressed the *Commit* button (without even pressing the Add button):

```
14:39:16.099: [get-learning] git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false add --ignore-errors -A -f -- main.py
14:39:16.106: [get-learning] git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false commit -F /private/var/folders/wy/sn6rs9nj1bd3bsk6p66gmwr40000gn/T/git-commit-msg-.txt --
```

I am not a Git expert, but I can see that the first command is an `add` command.

Does that mean PyCharm automatically adds the files before committing and I don't need to press the Add button before pressing the Commit button in PyCharm?

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes, pyCharm automatically adds

and even if it didn't, adding remains a fundamental part of committing.

> I know that we should first do `git add` before we do `git commit`.

Well, sometimes we have to, but this is irrelevant in pyCharm and more a general Git topic.

In your case, you are adding: `git ... add .. file.txt`. Should you do it with two separate actions? Well, it doesn't make much difference, since you are executing the same commands, does it?

In order to commit in Git, you'll always have to add first (either to the Index, or bypassing the Index momentarily and using temporary indexes - see below), then commit. If you don't feel like this is what you are doing, the interface is masking that for you - which is fairly common in most IDEs, but not your case.

---

*Do you really always have to add before committing?*

As correctly pointed out by matt, one might call `git commit ... <pathspec>`. From the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt-ltpathspecgt82308203):

> `<pathspec>`…​ When pathspec is given on the command line, commit the
> contents of the files that match the pathspec *without recording the*
> *changes already added to the index*. The contents of these files are
> also staged for the next commit on top of what have been staged
> before.

Italic mine. Basically, this creates a commit without taking the content from the staged area, but using the files you just provided. Kudos to matt for this, see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63905223/for-already-git-tracked-file-can-we-commit-changes-without-adding-them-in-git). So, in definitive, *no*, you don't have to strictly add, but Git will have to generate a Index and stage files before committing. So Git is adding, you like it or not.

Comment: "In order to commit in Git, you'll always have to add first, then commit" That is not strictly true.

Comment: @matt could you expand on this with an example?

Comment: You can just say `git commit ... myfile` and bypass the `add` completely. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63905223/for-already-git-tracked-file-can-we-commit-changes-without-adding-them-in-git

Comment: well, since git add is adding to the index, and that syntax adds them to the syntax, I somewhat fail to see the difference...

Comment: No, on the contrary it bypasses the index completely. Read my answer to the question.

Comment: Moreover `commit` has the `-a` modifier. So really you could go through a lifetime and barely ever say `add`. So to claim "you'll always have to add first, then commit" is just not accurate.

Comment: now, the pathspec is something I just learned today, kudos. the -a option is a shortcut calling to git add, from the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_examples).

Comment: That is true! I'm just saying that your strong claim about "you'll always have to add first" is wrong. I can use Git for hours and make many commits without ever issuing an `add` command.

Comment: You are indeed correct, I've update the answer to reflect that

Comment: @matt: `git commit <paths>` or `git commit --include <paths>` *does* actually add files to the, or an, index. The tricky part is that this is always a *temporary index*. Sometimes—with `--include`—this temporary index *becomes* the index, once the commit is finished and has worked; other times, there's yet a third index involved. But it really does all go into *some* index.

Comment: This used to be easier to see, when `git commit` was a shell script. :-) The include/only options would have to be implemented with environment variable overrides. I'm not sure that back in those shell-script days, `git commit` *had* the `--include` vs `--only` distinction, though. (The Git repository for Git has the answer, I'm just too lazy to go back to Git 1.5 or earlier to find it.)

Comment: @matt `git add` combines two distinct actions: it beings *tracking* a file if it is currently untracked, and it stages any changes from the tracked version. (In the case of a previously untracked file, the changes are relative to an empty file.) `git commit ...` can only stage-and-commit changes to files already being tracked; you have to use `add` explicitly  to being tracking an untracked file.

Comment: @chepner Absolutely. That's why I said "barely ever" - I didn't say "never".